# Can I access a non-type template class argument from outside? How?

Tags: c++, templates

Please check the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int Size>
class Test
{
  public:
    // Will not compile, if Size is not a type!
    // error: 'Size' does not name a type
    using MySize = Size;
    double array[Size];
};

using MyTestArray = Test<3>;

int main()
{
    MyTestArray testArray;

    std::cout << "Test array has size " << MyTestArray::MySize << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any possibility to access `Size` from outside without introducing a boilerplate getter like this?

```
constexpr static int getSize() 
{
    return Size;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, the problem isn't limited to *non-type* template parameters. So, for example, a vector<int> has a value_type member so you can get the int.

Comment: @BoP Yes, but for types one can also use `using`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a `constexpr static` variable with the value of the template parameter inside the class, for example

```
template <int Size>
class Test
{
  public:
    constexpr static auto MySize = Size;
    double array[Size];
};
```

Then you access like this

```
using MyTestArray = Test<3>;
auto size =  MyTestArray::MySize;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `decltype` specifier assuming a constness of the `MySize` variable. An example similar to the above post.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <int Size>
class Test
{
public:
    static const decltype(Size) MySize = Size;
    double array[Size];
};

using MyTestArray = Test<3>;

int main()
{
    MyTestArray testArray;

    std::cout << "Test array has size " << MyTestArray::MySize << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some boilerplate. Either add a static member to `Test` or if you do not want that or if you cannot modify `Test` you can use a type trait:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int Size> class Test {};

template <typename T> struct MySize;
template <int Size> struct MySize<Test<Size>> { static constexpr const int value = Size; };
template <typename T> constexpr const int MySize_v = MySize<T>::value;

int main()
{  
    std::cout << MySize_v<Test<3>>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <auto compile_time_known_parameter>
struct data
{
  static constexpr auto value = compile_time_known_parameter;
};

int main() { return data<64>::value; }
```

```
static constexpr auto value = compile_time_known_parameter;
```

`static` tells the compiler the storage must be in static memory

`constexpr` tells the compiler this is known at compile-time

`auto` tells the compiler to deduse the type automatically